# Configuring Flask and WSGI with Virtualenv

Tags: python, flask

I successfully configured an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine with Python 3.6, Apache and mod_wsgi. This folder has a virtualenv with Flask installed.

```
$ ls -l /var/www/html/odb/
  bin/
  lib/
  include/
  config.wsgi
```

The .wsgi file is very simple and so too is the Apache conf:

```
$ cat /var/www/html/odb/config.wsgi

  activate_this = '/home/ubuntu/odb/bin/activate_this.py'
  with open(activate_this) as file_:
  exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

  import sys
  sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/odb/')

  def application(environ,start_response):
      start_response('200 OK',[('Content-type','text/html')])
      return ['Hello world']

$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/odb.conf
  <VirtualHost *>
      ServerName example.com

      WSGIDaemonProcess webserver threads=5
      WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/odb/config.wsgi

      <Directory /var/www/html/odb>
          WSGIProcessGroup webserver
          WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
      </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

I can access the dummy web page. But when I modify the .wsgi file and add a Python Flask app I get an HTTP 500. Here are the files:

```
$ cat /var/www/html/odb/config.wsgi
  activate_this = '/home/ubuntu/odb/bin/activate_this.py'
  with open(activate_this) as file_:
      exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

  import sys
  sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/odb/')

  from webserver import app as application

$ cat /var/www/html/odb/webserver.py
  from flask import Flask
  app = Flask(__name__)

  @app.route('/')
  def hello_world():
      return 'Hello, World!'

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run the app via `$ flask run --host=0.0.0.0` I can access it via the internet so it seems that I am doing something wrong with how I point to the Flask app in .wsgi file. What am I doing wrong?

Logging: `$ cat /var/log/apache2/*log` gives nothing after a HTTP 500. I am noticing that `/var/www/html/odb/webserver.pyc` appears after a HTTP 500 if that can help..?

Comment: Long time since I've used Apache to serve WSGI, but the logs may give you an idea. Can you show the relevant logs (if memory serves they'll be in `error.logs`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I added a comment above now. No logs available.

Answer (score 0):

Believe you can get those logs by also enabling 'use_reloader' in the app.run() command,

Below from http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/

> 'if you do not set Keep in Mind
>   Flask will suppress any server error with a generic error page unless it is in >debug mode. As such to enable just the interactive debugger without the code >reloading, you have to invoke run() with debug=True and use_reloader=False. >Setting use_debugger to True without being in debug mode won’t catch any >exceptions because there won’t be any to catch.'

(Sorry cant comment, not enough points)